# OpenCart Insert/Update Products Api

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I am building a new online shop based on OpenCart 2. I am trying to integrate an supplier XML feed to automatically update product prices/stock info/etc. **Is there an ADD/UPDATE PRODUCT API to use with OpenCart 2?** Could not find any info on their site about this...

I analyzed the database diagram but I think it's very difficult to create a PHP code to add/update these products manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use existing code that opencart uses to add/update products. 
Its in *admin/model/catalog/product.php*.
There are methods for *addProduct* and *editProduct*.